# Convert OpenCV contour to Lines and Curves

Tags: python, opencv, computational-geometry

Is there a way to convert the contours extracted using OpenCV to convert/approximate them into Lines and Curves, probably forming a shape?

I am not that good in mathematics, any suggestion will be highly appreciated

Comment: Perhaps this [example](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d7/d1d/tutorial_hull.html) may help

Comment: What you are probably after is called *vectorization*. An approach to obtain lines is that of the Douglas-Peucker algorithm. It can be generalized to circular arcs, but I know of few references on this. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramer%E2%80%93Douglas%E2%80%93Peucker_algorithm https://hal.inria.fr/inria-00580123/document

Comment: @YvesDaoust thanks for the reference, it is very useful. I have to study it in detail though to implement in my project. Just out of curiosity, is there any programmatic implementation of this "Decomposition of a curve into arcs and line segments
based on dominant point detection" algorithm available?

Comment: I have no idea.

Comment: The implementations to extract lines and curves from contours that I know about are proprietary, and are used as the basis for some pattern-matching algorithms. If @YvesDaoust doesn't know of an algorithm, then that's a good indication you won't find one easily. TechAgnostic, I would urge you to pick a very specific application, provide a sample image or two, and then work from there. Solving problems like this in the general case is very hard, but applying a few engineering constraints could make it relatively straightforward. Maybe you don't need fully generalized code. Good luck!

Answer (score -2):

Bazier Curve for 3 points

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

im = np.zeros((480,640,3),dtype="uint8")

x1=100
y1=100
x2=300
y2=250
x3=200
y3=400

cv2.circle(im,(x1,y1),13,(0,255,0),3)
cv2.circle(im,(x2,y2),13,(0,255,0),3)
cv2.circle(im,(x3,y3),13,(0,255,0),3)

lx,ly=x1,y1
for tt in range(0,10,1):
    t=tt/10
    x = int((1-t)** 2 * x1 + 2 * (1-t) * t * x2 + t**2 * x3)
    y = int((1-t)** 2 * y1 + 2 * (1-t) * t * y2 + t**2 * y3)

    cv2.circle(im,(x,y),3,(0,0,255),3)
    cv2.line(im,(x,y),(lx,ly),(255,0,255),3)

    lx,ly = x,y


cv2.imshow('im',im)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

[image: Bazier Curve for 3 points]

You could apply the Bazier Curve formula using 3 points at a time from countours points

```
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv
im = cv.imread('test.jpg')
imgray = cv.cvtColor(im, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ret, thresh = cv.threshold(imgray, 127, 255, 0)
contours, hierarchy = cv.findContours(thresh, cv.RETR_TREE, cv.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
```

more info:
https://docs.opencv.org/master/d4/d73/tutorial_py_contours_begin.html

Draw contours

```
image = cv2.drawContours(image,contours,-1,(0,0,255),3)
```

Or you can draw polylines  from contours points

```
for contour in contours:
    image = cv2.polylines(image, [contour],  
                      isClosed, (0,255,0), 3)
```

more info here: https://docs.opencv.org/master/dc/da5/tutorial_py_drawing_functions.html

Comment: I don't think that this answer is relevant. The OP knows that.

Comment: I don't know the OP.  Hope Bazier Curve may be of interest to you

Comment: The OP *said* he can extract contours. I never heard of any "Bazier".